# go mod tidy gives operation not permitted messages

Tags: go

Why does running go mod tidy give me these messages in the terminal?

```
go mod tidy
pattern all: open /Users/Jumpman/.Trash: operation not permitted
```

There are a handful of these messages with different paths all ending with operation not permitted. For reference I'm using go version 1.17

Comment: What's appropriate for go module permissions aren't appropriate for everything.   Home directory is too wide a place to put a go module.   It really has to be in its own directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every go module should be in a dedicated directory.   Yours appears to be within your home directory.

Create a subdirectory within your home directory,  and move `go.mod`, `go.sum`, and your go code there.